# How to retrieve data from Parse into NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to get data from Parse into an NSArray. Here is my code:

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];

[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

[query includeKey:@"message"];


[query whereKey:@"Reciever" hasPrefix:@"jbokwxguy"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
                PFObject *post = object[@"body"];
                NSLog(@"retrieved related post: %@", post);
            }
        } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

}];

_messages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
          @"Hello, how are you.",
          @"I'm great, how are you?",
          @"I'm fine, thanks. Up for dinner tonight?",
          @"Glad to hear. No sorry, I have to work.",
          @"Oh that sucks. A pitty, well then - have a nice day.."
          @"Thanks! You too. Cu soon.",

          nil];

[super awakeFromNib];
```

}

I am trying to get the post data from:

```
NSLog(@"retrieved related post: %@",post);
```

into _messages, which is an NSArray. I am creating a simple chat application and this is my only stumbling block. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you just trying to add all of the "post" objects you get into _messages?

Comment: Your query, as a part of its completion block, returns an `NSArray` of `PFObject`s. Question 1: To be clear, you would like the values from each `(PFObject*)post` to be added to your _messages array? Question 2: To be clear, the `_messages` array in your question code is simply an example?

Comment: @bjtitus: That is exactly what I am trying to do. And

Comment: @andrewbuilder Queston 1 I want yes and Question 2, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick glimpse to your code it looks good. I can suppose that the query is coming back empty... Check the query results before assuming your code is broken... Try :

---

```
[query whereKey:@"Reciever" hasPrefix:@"jbokwxguy"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"Array: %@", objects);               
}];
```

If this code shows you the objects in the console, your set to go... If not, the error should lie in the query it self :

HINT: Maybe the "hasPrefix:@"jbokwxguy"];" is returning zero results? 
Also might be that  "Reciever" Should be spelled "Receiver" ???

If you don't get results, try removing the query constraints and try getting all the objects and start from there.....

You can also try objects.count to see how many objects are in the array.

NOTE that you are getting back : PFObject ... So you might need to drill down for the contents...

BTW: As a chat app. Maybe this approach is not the best solution out there.. It might be slow... It can work as a commenting system, but for chat, the whole parse database thing... Might be too slow for a reliable chat.. Any way this is only my opinion! You can check some IP streaming solutions....

---

Update for comment: 
(I am unable to comment, so i would update my answer here) :

You will get back an NSArray of PFObject's.. So in order to retrieve the contents of your post, you need to get the properties out of the PFObject... You should iterate thru all PFObjects and extract the "body" property from the PFOBject like so:

```
[query whereKey:@"Reciever" hasPrefix:@"jbokwxguy"];
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSString *post = [object objectForKey:@"body"];
        NSLog(@"retrieved related post: %@", post);
    }                
  }];
```

If it fails to throw you the "BODY" check your spelling and the existence of the "body" field in the parse database.

** Please if this answers your question, please mark the answer correct. It helps me to keep helping other people.  Thanks!

Comment: The code returns two objects. And I understand that it could be slow once a user base is created, but for now it is a quick and easy option to get the app ready for beta testing. I am just having trouble converting the "body" returns to a NSArray.

Comment: I am not able to get the contents into an NSMutableArray to convert to the NSArray. With the following code:     posts = [object objectForKey:@"body"]; [m1 addObject:posts];`

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at firebase.com , It's architected to sync data aside from serving data. It will work great for chatrooms and more.